# You just pulled a

Tags: symbols, shorthand

I'm writing a paper about a book. In the the book there is a character named Johnny,and Johnny is very stupid.

For fun let's say my friend did something stupid, and I said, "You just pulled a Johnny!" That would mean that:

Johnny is the new ___ for idiotcracy.

What would go in the ___

Thanks! The closest thing I could come to is *shorthand*, but that isn't quite correct.

Comment: I would say "metaphor".

Comment: Another possibility is _eponym_ or _eponymous term_.

Comment: *Namesake* is a less posh variation of *eponym*.

Answer (score -1):

I think "euphemism" would be the best choice for what you are doing, but "definition (of)" could also work.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You need to support your answer with a  reference/research/link, etc. "I think" answer is not considered a good answer here. Thanks.